# Como colocar o retorno do Ajax [formulário] dentro de uma div?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'executa.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {emailDestino: emailDestino},
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data) {
        $('#notifyInscrito').appendTo(data);
    }   
});
```

Estou indo lá no arquivo `executa.php` via ajax com um e-mail, e fazendo uma consulta para montar um HTML com os dados retornados, e quero colocar esse HTML completo dentro da `div` `#notifyInscrito`. Que é uma lightbox que logo em seguida vai enviar um e-mail para o registro dos dados retornados.

Eu tentei fazer um `$('#notifyInscrito').appendTo(data)` na intenção dele retornar o formulário de dentro do `executa.php` e inserir dentro da `div` mas não funcionou.

Pergunta: Como pegar o HTML do `executa.php` e colocar dentro da `div` `#notifyInscrito`?

Comment: Coloca as informações do ficheiro `executa.php`

Comment: O `dataType` tem `Default = String`, remova o `dataType` para ele tratar como texto puro, ou altere para `text`.

Comment: utilize a função `.html()` ao invés de `.appendTo()`

Answer (score 4):

O "data" que é retornado a você é um objeto, deve ser lido como `data.algumacoisa` ou `data['algumacoisa']`.

Procure usar uma função no executa.php que faça um retorno de algum TEXTO para você, porque você definiu um HTML como `dataType`, ou seja: Texto.

Você pode fazer este seguinte código:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'executa.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {emailDestino: emailDestino},
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data) {
        $('#notifyInscrito').html(data.algumacoisa);
    }   
});
```